# Hibernate complex collection mapping trouble

Tags: hibernate, collections, dictionary, annotations, mapping

I have entities with complex mappings which I fail to annotate right.

Here are the entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "bank")
class Bank {
    @Column(name = "type")
    int type

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "bank_fp", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "bank_id"))
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "finance_percent")
    Map<Double, BankRates>
}

? embeddable or entity ?
class BankRates {
    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "bankrates", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "bfp_id"))
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "track_class")
    Map<String, TrackRates>
}

? embeddable or entity ?
class TrackRates {
    ? how to map ?
    Map<YearsRange, Double>
}

@Embeddable
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
class YearsRange {
    @Column(name = "from")
    int from
    @Column(name = "to")
    int to
}
```

Seems to me those are the tables:

```
Bank: id, type
bank_fp: id, bank_id, finance_percent - table for the map in the bank entity
bank_rates: bfp_id, track_class, from, to, rate - table for BankRates, TrackRates, YearsRange all embedded in a single table cuz its only mappings
```

Those of you who are hibernate mapping superbs
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

`@entity class BankRates` since it has its own id

since `bank_rates` contains a lot of duplicates of (bfp_id, track_class) you can not map it like that you have to implement the map logic yourself

```
class BankRates {
    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "bankrates", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "bfp_id"))
    List<TrackRate>

}

@Embeddable
class TrackRate {
    @Column(name = "track_class")
    String trackClass;
    YearsRange
    Double
}

@Embeddable
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
class YearsRange {
    @Column(name = "from")
    int from
    @Column(name = "to")
    int to
}
```